# Using "How's you doing?" and its variations

Tags: phrase-usage

What are the common situations to use this phrase *How's you doing?*
Could it be related to something specific? For example to News?

I've seen the phrase: [How's Your News?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How's_Your_News)

What does *'s* stand for? Is *News* a plural? If *news* is plural, how is the phrase used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrases in use are "how are you doing?" (with the *'re* contraction, usually, since it's a conventional phrase), and "what's new?" or "what's the news?".  I've never heard "how's your news?" said by a native speaker (I just checked your pointer to the wiki article:  that's a very specific use that doesn't extend to ordinary speech and sounds strange even as a professional question).

In the phrase "what's the news?", *is* is used because "news" is what's known as a *collective singular*.  Collective singulars have a plural form, but are seen as an aggregate, thus taking the singular verb.

English doesn't use "new" as a noun, it's always an adjective in singular form.  Saying "what's the new?" where "new" is a noun (as opposed to "what's new?", where new is an adjective), sounds very strange and unnatural.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recognise "How's you doing" as Standard English. There are probably English variants where people do say this, and if I would heard it I would assume that the speaker either used one of those dialects, or was pretending to do so.

As MMacD says, "How's your news?" is not a familiar question, and "news" is not plural.